# Is Ubuntu TV included in 14.04?

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-tv

Is TV included in 14.04? or is it an addon? My tuners are Quad from digitalnow in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not available in 14.04.

At this time Ubuntu TV is only supported on Ubuntu 12.04. If you do not have 12.04 and would still like to help out we suggest that you use a virtual machine for now.

Warning This will replace the Unity 2d that is installed on your system. you will still be able to use unity 2d desktop but it will be altered.

If you are running 12.04 and would like to try this on your system. This is how to do that.

open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

enter in

```
sudo apt-get -y build-dep unity-2d
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:u2t/bleedingedge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install unity-2d-shell
```

That is it reboot and pick unity-2d when logging into Ubuntu.

Source: [*UbuntuTV/Contributing*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing)